# DHTMLX "onEditCell" event called after "onClick" button event

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I have `dhtmlXGridObject` named `mGrid`.

I have attached validation event:

```
mGrid.attachEvent("onEditCell", function(stage, rId, cInd, nValue, oValue){...});
```

Also I have save button:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onClick="onSaveClick();" />
```

All works fine except one situation:
If I edit the data and leaving the cursor in the cell and click "Save" then the method "onSaveClick" is called first and only then "onEditCell" is called.

How can I perform calling "onEditCell" before "onSaveClick"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Try closing the cell-editor first in your `onSaveClick()` function. This will trigger the `onEditCell` event.

```
function onSaveClick(){
    mGrid.editStop();

    //Your code...
}
```

[Dhtmlx documentation editStop](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3aapi_method_dhtmlxgridobject_editstop)

Comment: Thank you, Hazaart. Works as expected